# How do you grep results from 'find'?

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, find

Trying to find a word/pattern contained within the resulting file names of the find command.

For instance, I have this command:

`find . -name Gruntfile.js` that returns several file names.

How do I grep within these for a word pattern?

Was thinking something along the lines of:

`find . -name Gruntfile.js | grep -rnw -e 'purifycss'`

However, this is doesn't work..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `-exec {} +` option to pass the list of filenames that are found as arguments to grep:

```
find -name Gruntfile.js -exec grep -nw 'purifycss' {} +
```

This is the safest and most efficient approach, as it doesn't break when the path to the file isn't "well-behaved" (e.g. contains a space). Like an approach using `xargs`, it also minimises the number of calls to grep by passing multiple filenames at once.

I have removed the `-e` and `-r` switches, as I don't think that they're useful to you here.

---

An excerpt from `man find`:

> `-exec command {} +`
> This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by appending  each  selected               file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files.

Comment: Readers may find it useful to know that you can use `-exec cmd \;` as a predicate in a longer find expression. For example, let's suppose OP were to want to stage matching gruntfiles in git. `find -name Gruntfile.js -exec grep -qw purifycss {} \; -exec git add {} +`

Comment: What does `-exec {} +` do though? Especially the `{} +` part? Could someone add it to the answer?

Comment: @Harvastum I added an excerpt from `man find` to the answer, you can read the rest there.

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't strictly answer your question, provided you have globstar turned on (`shopt -s globstar`), you could filter the results in bash like this:

```
grep something **/Gruntfile.js
```

I was using religiously the approach used by Tom Fenech until I switched to zsh, which handles such things *much* better. Now all I do is:

```
grep text **/*(.)
```

which greps text through all regular files in current directory.

I believe this to be much cleaner syntax especially for day-to-day work in shell.

Comment: `globstar` is supported by bash too and is a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

When too many files exist for the * expansion to run:

```
$ grep -o 'xxmaj\|xxbos\|xxfld' train/* | wc -l
-bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long
0
```

Then this code fixes the “too long” problem:

```
$ find junk -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs grep -o 'TVDetails\|xxmaj\|xxbos\|xxfld' 
junk/gum-.doc.out:TVDetails
junk/Zv0n.doc.out:TVDetails
$ find junk -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs grep -o 'TVDetails\|xxmaj\|xxbos\|xxfld' | wc -l
2
```

It runs faster on my system, and maybe yours, when using the -P 0 option:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%E Elapsed Real Time" find train -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -P 0 grep -o 'TVDetails\|xxmaj\|xxbos\|xxfld' | wc -l
0:02.45 Elapsed Real Time
358
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%E Elapsed Real Time" find train -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs grep -o 'TVDetails\|xxmaj\|xxbos\|xxfld' | wc -l
0:11.96 Elapsed Real Time
358
```

Hope this helps.